# Upgrade JFrog Artifactory Professional 5.6.2 to 6.23.33

Tags: artifactory

I am new to artifactory and I am suppose to work on upgrading artifactory professional 5.6.2 to 6.23.33 version, I am not able to locate any specific documentation for performing same. Please help to find the right documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade to version 6.23.x, First you need to upgrade to 6.10. This is because there are breaking changes in this version with respect to database structure etc. Please refer to this [confluence page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory) for the complete details. You can pick the upgrade process according to the type of installation (like zip/rpm/docker etc)
So, it will be two-step upgrade.